# How to make inline LabelFields

Tags: blackberry, java-me, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

I'm working in a Blackberry app (OS 5.0) and need to show recent tweets of the user.
I'm able to get the data from Twitter's end. Now after parsing the entities (hashtags, urls, user-mentions etc), I need to display them with separate formatting (color, bold etc). So I'm using different LabelFields for different parts of the tweet.
But LabelFields are by default block elements. How do I put those LabelFields inline, so that it looks like how it is shown in Twitter?

like this:
[image]

Comment: Try RichTextField. If it doesn't fit your problem then you need to write your own RichTextField like class with click-able support in sub text of the original text.

Comment: @Rupak Okay.. can you tell me how I can make a part of RichTextField clickable? How should I handle touchEvent and navigationClick?  Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure if this can be achieved using `RichTextField`. But you can give a try.
There are methods in `RichTextField` for getting cursor position `public int getCursorPosition()`, getting formatting region using cursor position `int getRegion(int offset)`, and getting cookie for that region `public Object getRegionCookie(int region)`.
And also it is possible to construct `RichTextField` with an array of formatting region parameters using `public RichTextField(String text, int[] offsets, byte[] attributes, Font[] fonts, Object[] cookies, long style)`.

Comment: So it may be possible to decide what to do in `navigationClick` method by considering current cursor position, formatting region etc.

Comment: How many of these fields do you have to display?  Is there a limit to how many tweets are shown?  I'm just asking to get a feeling for how important performance will be for you.

Comment: @Nate 20 recent tweets are to be displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that there's a component in Blackberry SDK called ActiveRichTextField which automatically scans its contents and parses links making them focusable and clickable. Furthur it'll also parse entities if Twitter app is installed in that device. For now it solves my problem. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1):

Others have suggested RichTextField but you'd have to write your own text filter to colour the syntax - it's going to be a lot of effort. If having the clickable links inline is a must then personally I'd use a BrowserField but that would mean your logic would have to output a full screens worth of tweets into html (screens don't like having more than one browserfield - it's doable with more than one but there's some hacks) and manage the click events - more complications.

Alternatively you could do something like this: http://devblog.blackberry.com/2009/10/how-to-use-table-view-layout/ You wouldn't have clickable regions within the text body but it'd still be using native fields instead of 'cheating' with markup, probably the best way.